# smsClient.send() return value meaning?

Tags: asp.net, sms-gateway, way2sms

I were searching for this question over internet for days but it seems no one has discussed about it before. I am using `SmsClient.dll` to send msg using way2sms service but when I send command `sms.send(ID, password, smsBody, tonumber);` execute it returns a value that is always 2 and examples in internet says there is problem in internet connection, but here is the funny thing. My internet connection is working absolutely fine.

Here is my couple of question :

1. what are the return value indicates(if different from the code value please suggest or if you find some developer guide for SMSClient.dll)?
2. if return value indicates correct reason in my code, what is the problem in my code that is giving me return value "2".

here is my code:

```
private string SendSMSFromWAY2SMS(string tonumber, string ID, String password, string smsBody)
{
    string result = null;
    SendSms sms = new SendSms();
    string status = sms.send(ID, password, smsBody, tonumber);
    if (status == "1")
    {
        result = "Sending Sms ";
    }
    else if (status == "2")
    {
        result = "Please Check Your Internet Connection";
    }
    else
    {
        result="Invalid Password or User Name";
    }

    result = "Your Daily Sms Limit Was Completed \nso Please Try with  Another Account";
    return result;

}
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: did you read their documentation?

Comment: I managed to open the dll file and there it was returning 2 if Exception occurs regardless of exception type. I started to use the native code directly in my code but I am getting service unavailable error.